# Extension Traits for Typescript

Tags: typescript

Imagine the following scenario. You have a class A that has a method that can create an instance of the class B. You can't edit the code of neither A or B (like in a external library).

In this scenario if you wanted to extend the functionality of B, you could for instance create a new class C that extends B, and implement the new functionality in C. However, the method of A that returns B will still return B, and not the class with the new functionality that you wanted to add to B. If you wanted the method to return C, what you could do is create a new class D that extends A and overrides the method that returns B to return C. This could get out of hand, for instance if classes E-Z also implement methods that return an instance of B that you'd like to have the new methods implemented in C.

In Rust you can use [extension traits](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0445-extension-trait-conventions.html) to extend the functionality of a struct by adding new methods to it, and the new methods will be available to all instances of that struct. So in the previous example, we could implement a new trait BExt for B, and the instance of B that is returned by the method of A would have the methods implemented in BExt. Is it possible to do something similar in typescript? Or in other words, is it possible to add a method to all instances of a class without modifying the original implementation of the class? Or as an alteranive, can you extend the functionality of a class, and have all methods that return an instance of the class return an object with the extended functionality?

Example:

```js
//lib.ts
class B {}

class A {
 static getB(): B { return new B(); }
```

```js
//index.ts
import {A, B} from "lib.ts"


//Add a new method to B in some way, for instance:
addMethod(B, "helloWorld", () => console.log("Hello World"));

A.getB().helloWorld() // ok;
```

Note that the addMethod function here is only for the purposes of the example, it does not have to actually be a function, just a way of adding a new method to B.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could provide a [mre] others could use to make suggestions.  In the abstract I'd say you could modify `A.prototype` and `B.prototype`, but without a concrete example it's hard to know if that would work as you intend.  Please consider [edit]ing to provide some specific code here.

Comment: Thanks.  Does [this approach](https://codesandbox.io/s/tsplay-yc9lll?file=/index.ts) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! It does meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get the behavior you're talking about in JavaScript is to add methods to [the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) of the existing class constructor.  Like this:

```
import { A, B } from "./lib";

B.prototype.helloWorld = function () {
  console.log("Hello World");
};

A.getB().helloWorld(); // "Hello World"
```

That works at runtime, but the TypeScript compiler will complain because it doesn't think that `B` has a `helloWorld()` method.  You need to let the compiler know about it by [merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) the new method signature into the interface corresponding to the class.  Since you imported it from a module, you would use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to do that:

```
declare module "./lib" {
  interface B {
    helloWorld(): void;
  }
}
```

And now that will compile without error also.

---

Do note that modifying existing prototypes isn't necessarily *recommended*.  Any code in the existing class or elsewhere that doesn't expect such a change could break.  Or your modification could break when someone else makes a change that conflicts with it.  Generally speaking it's best not to tinker with things this way, although in particular cases it could be warranted.

[Codesandbox link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/tsplay-yc9lll?file=/index.ts)